# Should I add nofollow tag to search label links on blogger?

Tags: seo, blogger, nofollow

I have 2 questions about SEO on blogger. (I have a custom domain)

1. Should I add 'nofollow' tag to search label links on blogger? (found in my blog Menu and somewhere in the blog posts) `"domain.com/search/label/......"`
2. Similar question, I'm using subdomains (with URL masking) to make the search labels links more user-friendly (for desktop users only). should I nofollow them too? BTW those pages are indexed, but I don't care about their ranking, the question is if adding a nofollow tag for subdomains that are not important, will do any damage?

For example `"category1.domain.com"` is masked URL for `"http://domain.com/search/label/category1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**: You should not add the `nofollow` attribute to (any) internal links.

**Long Answer**: What you're describing sounds suspicious: masking; nofollow; user agent redirects.

I don't know if they'll do any damage but I don't think they'll help so why risk it?

`nofollow` was invented to prevent comment spam from passing PageRank, in effect indicating the publishing site "doesn't trust" the link.

When a link has the `nofollow` attribute [Google no longer passes that PageRank to other links on the page, it simply evaporates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow#Introduction_and_support).

Blogger is built and hosted by Google, I'm pretty sure it's search engine friendly right out of the box.